# Mcrypt extension required on windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I am working on a site that uses an older version of laravel and php. And I keep getting this error when I try to run php artisan with laravel. Is there a way to maybe install an older version of laravel or php. Or how can I  install mcrypt? I downloaded a file from PECL but I don't understand how to install it. Also when I try to find `php.ini` inside the directory stated in `phpinfo()` I cannot see it.

Comment: which version of php and laravel is the site using?
and which are you using on your local environment?

Comment: What is the exact error line?

Comment: Website is using laravel 4.2.11 but I don't know what version of PHP it is because I don't have access to cpanel. I'll let you know when I learn. I am using the newest version of laravel and PHP 7.3

Comment: Exact error is "Mycrpt php extension required". When I try to run php artisan codes or when I try to run the site on a local server.